# Literature on optimizing linear objectives over non-convex sets

Tags: reference-request, optimization, non-convex-optimization

I was trying to find related literature on linear optimization problems with a non-convex constraint set. Could you provide links to the related literature? Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the non-convex constraints?

Comment: Thanks@RodrigodeAzevedo . I mean general non-convex constraints.

Comment: Any nonconvex optimization problem can be cast as an equivalent problem with linear objective, so what you want to search for is "simply" the area of nonconvex optimization.